# XAML margin error

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I am trying to generate a dynamic form on windows universal app and having a problem with the margin.

I like to keep both Radiobutton and Textbox to be on the left side at margin 0.
The problem is somehow the Textbox can't stay on the left, i have both controls with the margin left at 0, somehow the textbox was pushing to the right of the screen.

This is the result after I ran the app.

The output result for Windows Universal app on Windows 10
[image: The output result for Windows Universal app on Windows 10]

My script file name MainPage.xaml.cs for project AppTestTrash

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
namespace AppTestTrash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Add dynamic RadioButton
            var dynamicRadiobtn = new RadioButton();
            dynamicRadiobtn.Name = "testme";
            dynamicRadiobtn.Height = 30;
            dynamicRadiobtn.Width = 50;
            dynamicRadiobtn.Margin = new Thickness(0, 100, 0, 0);
            dynamicForm.Children.Add(dynamicRadiobtn);

            //Add dynamic texbox
            var dynamicTextbox = new TextBox();
            dynamicTextbox.Name = "testme2";
            dynamicTextbox.Height = 30;
            dynamicTextbox.Width = 50;
            dynamicTextbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 120, 0, 0);
            dynamicForm.Children.Add(dynamicTextbox);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML file mainpage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="AppTestTrash.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppTestTrash"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">

    <Grid Name="mainGrid"  BorderBrush="AliceBlue"  Width="500" Height="500" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="2">
        <StackPanel Name="dynamicForm" BorderThickness="1">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this issue, you can set `dynamicTextbox`'s [HorizontalAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_HorizontalAlignment) property to [Left](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.horizontalalignment) like the following.

```
//Add dynamic texbox
var dynamicTextbox = new TextBox();
dynamicTextbox.Name = "testme2";
dynamicTextbox.Height = 30;
dynamicTextbox.Width = 50;
dynamicTextbox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
dynamicTextbox.Margin = new Thickness(0, 120, 0, 0);
dynamicForm.Children.Add(dynamicTextbox);
```

The default value of `HorizontalAlignment` is **Stretch**, so your text box will be on the center of your grid even the left margin is 0. For more info, please see **Remarks** of [HorizontalAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_HorizontalAlignment).